# Execute concurrently SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing some `exec` in a store procedure, Is there a way to execute simultaneously those exec, they are independent so there are no race conditions...

Also, I am doing things (really more complex) like:

```
SET @template = 'SELECT FROM ... INSERT ...'
SET @template2 = 'SELECT FROM ... INSERT ...'
EXEC(@template);
EXEC(@template2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to have your code call each of the EXEC commands asynchronously. SQL Server has no way to explicitly execute stored procedures asynchronously.

Note also that executing them asynchronously may or may not improve performance.

Comment: I mean use ADO.NET to execute the queries asynchronously, using BeginExecuteQuery, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to open two query windows from SQL Server Management Studio and execute both sets of commands in the two windows.

**Query Window 1**

```
SET @template = 'SELECT FROM ... INSERT ...'
EXEC(@template);
```

**Query Window 2**

```
SET @template2 = 'SELECT FROM ... INSERT ...'
EXEC(@template2);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that in the same window in the same code?

Comment: No not exactly.  You would need to run asynchronous calls though external code like C# ADO.Net